# Why does Windows Defender suddenly classify %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts as HostsFileHijack?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I've installed the MVPS Hosts blacklist to my etc\hosts file in order not to be tracked. Today, Windows Defender scared me by telling me it detected `SettingsModifier:Win32/HostsFileHijack` in spite of the file being in place unchanged for over a year.

This is clearly a false alert but what triggered that? An updated version of Defender and a process that attempted to read the file? Or the OS "forgetting" I modified this file?

[Microsoft's description](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=SettingsModifier%3aWin32%2fHostsFileHijack&threatid=265754) for Defender under Windows 10 is not helpful, while they have a [useful page for Windows 8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2764944/hosts-file-is-detected-as-malware-in-windows-defender).

The detection occurred after starting Microsoft Teams (which crashed).

Comment: It's likely due to the modifications you have done to your hosts file.  Windows Defender signatures are updated multiple times a day.  I personally would just ignore the finding and classify it as a false positive.

Comment: If you look at your hosts file and you assure yourself it is fine, then WD has a false positive and you can whitelist it in Threat Protection settings. Test:   Move the Hosts file to a USB key and make a Hosts file with two lines each #  . Save and restart , test. Notepad must be opened with Run as Administrator to edit HOSTS and save it.

Comment: @Ramhound The MVPS `hosts` file entries do not interfere with Windows Defender on any version of Windows 10.

Comment: @JW0914 - Why are you telling me that?

Comment: @Ramhound due to your comment above stating _"It's likely due to the modifications you have done to your hosts file"_

Comment: Please add the output from the following to your question:`icacls C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, as the MVPS `hosts` entries do not cause the issue being experienced. Please also try [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Hosts/hosts) known-good `hosts` file _(it's MVPS + Malware Domain Lists & is the one I use)_, as modifying the hosts file in this context will not generate the aforementioned error on any version of Windows 10 / 8. _(I never replace the `hosts` file, instead, I open both and copy/paste the content from MVPS' `hosts` into the system's.)_

Comment: @JW0914 - If it was a false positive, and the signature was fixed already, there is no way to validate my theory.  I used MVPS a few years ago, and remember fighting my security software, but that wasn’t Windows Defender.  The detection of the modification to the file was likely due to the fact Microsoft Teams crashed more than likely.  I have experienced similar issues when I used MVPS, won’t put a date on that, since it was one of my biggest regrets in my career.

Comment: @Ramhound The MVPS `hosts` file has never created a false positive on any version of Windows 10/8 (it redirects to `0.0.0.0` after all); however, what likely can are improper permissions, as only users belonging to the `Administrators` group can modify the `hosts` file. A simple thought experiment can rule out false positives: the `hosts` file is one of the only files in `%WinDir%` that can be modified w/o issue because it's a file that's intended to be user-modified, therefore hash comparisons on the file never occur as they do with most other system files, leaving only an ACL issue.

Comment: A permission issue does not explain type of detection.  You are saying with a 100% affirmative that this was not a false positive.  Yet; The author is here due to the fact Windows Defender detected something.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't articulate my point clearly enough: I'm not saying the author's `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file isn't the issue, only that the MVPS `hosts` file's content is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your hosts file also includes entries to block Windows Telemetry? This is a possible reason for your file to be marked as infected:

> Microsoft is now using Windows Defender feature to prevent users from
> blocking telemetry collection by editing their hosts file, which could
> be due to security or other reasons.

https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/09/07/windows-10-defender-flags-hosts-file-telemetry-blocking/